Closed subsets in Fell topology on $\mathcal{P}(G)$
I am currently working with a discrete group $G$. I am considering a  set $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(G)$ of finite subsets $F \subseteq G$ whose cardinalities are uniformly bounded. I am having troubles understanding why this $A$ is compact in the Fell topology of $\mathcal{P}(G)$.
I am not very familiar with such Fell topology: I have read the definition and basic facts, for example I know that it is always compact. Thus, it would suffice to show that the set $A$ is closed in order to obtain compactness.
How do I use the fact that the cardinality of the sets in $A$ is bounded to get that $A$ is closed in the Fell topology of $\mathcal{P}(G)$?
Thank you for your help.

I don’t think that is the case. Consider the set ${{g}:g\in G}$. It is uniformly bounded, but seems to be dense; a set of the form ${A\subset G: A\cap U\neq \emptyset}$ for open (arbitrary by discreteness) $U$ intersects it nontrivially whenever $U$ is nonempty, and similarly for ${A\subseteq G: A\cap K=\emptyset}$ for compact (finite by discreteness) $K$. Am I missing something?
